# Android Google Maps go to current location without animation

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this might be a little silly and I must have missed something but how do I disable that animation that zooms in all the way to my marker and load up google maps and my current location immediately?

This is my current code

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        String curr_location = currentLocation.getLatitude()+ ","+currentLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate current = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates,15);
        googleMap.animateCamera(current);
        UpdateLocation(userid,email,curr_location);
    }
```

I'd like to remove the animate camera if possible. thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Replace

```
googleMap.animateCamera(current);
```

with

```
googleMap.moveCamera(current);
```

[(Reference)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate))