# Android: Google Maps Camera animation

Tags: android, google-maps

How to animate (move) camera towards the current position (the blue dot) without using onLocationChanged deliberately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Maps go to current location without animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692476/android-google-maps-go-to-current-location-without-animation)

Comment: What do you mean by "first time?"  Typically the animation would only occur once, on map load, or possibly after a change in orientation.  The duplicate link should cover you.

Comment: Its not what is mentioned in your suggested question. I want to animate camera first time but not every time whenever map hosting fragment comes to foreground, when user navigate through different fragments using tabs in bottom navigation view.

Comment: Then maintain state which either does a move or an animation.  Anyway, without seeing your code an exact answer cannot be given.

Comment: Ok thanks Tim. I already know that solution but I just want to know that is there any method or callback which googleMaps provide for getting it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really on the fence between a comment and an answer, but I think you can get the behavior you want by just using an activity level boolean flag.  Initially, this flag would be set to true.  If true, you would animate your Google map.  Otherwise, you would not animate.  Something like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private boolean firstRender = true;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        CameraUpdate current = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates,15);
        if (firstRender) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(current);
            firstRender = false;
        }
        else {
            googleMap.moveCamera(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I already did same. As I mentioned in comment above. :)

Comment: What about those points which l lost as per your saying of possible dublicate? Although its not dublicate

Comment: @SubhanAli Initially I thought it was an exact duplicate but then decided it was not.  But seriously...you lost points?

Comment: Yes it was about 10 points. Anyways you deserve an upvote. Thanks for your coordination. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just move ur camera instead of animateCamera onMapReady: mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(ur location))

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng chennai = new LatLng(new GPSTracker(activity).getLatitude(), new GPSTracker(activity).getLongitude());
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(chennai, 12));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(chennai).title("Marker in chennai"));
    }
```